# add multiple values (array) to post meta_input

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, wp-insert-post

i have a custom post type where a post is generated by a form submit. One key is an array which should be stored in a custom field... i shortended the code below to the important part -> they key is "event_musikstil"

```
'meta_input' => array(                          
             // Custom Fields
                'event_musikstil' => foreach( $event_musikstil as $item ) { add_post_meta( $post_id, "_event_musikstil", $item ); },
                )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply store the meta as an array... Also to hell with add_post_meta... I never use it.  update defaults to add if the meta doesn't exist for the post.

```
update_post_meta($post_id, "_event_musikstil", $event_musikstil);
```

wordpress will store the value as a serialized array then so just retrieve it like

```
get_post_meta($post_id, "_event_musikstil", TRUE);
```

Hope this helps.

Another way, if you don't want to store a serialized array is to use explode and implode

```
        $metaStr = get_post_meta($post_id, 'your_key', true);
        if(!empty($metaStr)){
            $meta_arr = explode(',', $metaStr); // assuming you stored as , separated
        }else{
            $meta_arr = []; // empty array
        }
        foreach($newValuesToAdd as $newValueToAdd) {
            $meta_arr[] = $newValueToAdd;
        }
       update_post_meta($post_id, 'your_key', implode(',',$meta_arr));
```

Comment: Curious to the down vote as word-press saves serialized arrays and retrieves with no issue.  I supposed I could answer the question using explode and implode method to save as a comma separated string.